# PHP || conditional statement is not giving correct result when check not empty or a string

Tags: php, html, conditional-statements

I have the following `php` conditions whereby if a variable is not empty it will show the following

```
if (!empty($ot1Oa)){
    echo ' <span style="font-weight:bold; color:green"> OT1:</span><span style="color:green">'.$ot1Oa.'</span>';
}
```

But after the actual trial, I noticed sometimes there is a chance that it can have a string value of `-`. I wanted to include this condition also in my previous code with and `||` statement and I modified as below

```
if (!empty($ot1Oa) || $ot1Oa != "-"){
   echo ' <span style="font-weight:bold; color:green"> OT1:</span><span style="color:green">'.$ot1Oa.'</span>';
}
```

What I meant is if not empty `$ot1Oa` or if `$ot1Oa` is not equal to `-`, then show the `html`. But somehow it is not working. My code grabbing `$ot1Oa == "-"` from database. But the `html` still showing.

Does anyone who why?

Comment: If `$ot10a == "-"` then it's not empty, so it's shown.

Comment: I think you want `&&`, not `||`.

Comment: @Barmar Oh yes...such a silly mistake in logic! It must be &&

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are checking if the value for `$ot1Oa` is assigned and it's not `-` you have to use an `and` operator without using `or` operator.

Change this:

```
if (!empty($ot1Oa) || $ot1Oa != "-"){
```

to:

```
if (!empty($ot1Oa) && $ot1Oa != "-"){
```

I hope this will help you.